# Incompatible conditional operand types void and String

Tags: java

I want to change the value of `computeDto.getPharmacie().getMotiRefuse()` with "traitement en chevauchement non pris en charge " it doesnt work for me, I got this error `Incompatible conditional operand types void and String!` how can I edit it please!
here is my code:

```java
Map result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
long dureeTrait=Long.parseLong(dureeTraitement);

if(difference_In_Days > dureeTrait) {
    result.put("motifPharmacie",
        computeDto.getPharmacie().getMotiRefuse()
        != null ? computeDto.getPharmacie().getMotiRefuse(): "");
} 
else {
    result.put("motifPharmacie",
        computeDto.getPharmacie().getMotiRefuse()
        != null ? computeDto.getPharmacie().setMotiRefuse("traitement en chevauchement non pris en charge "): "");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post the full code for "setMotiRefuse()" method. but i assume it is a regular setter method that returns void.

The issue is in this line of code

```
result.put("motifPharmacie",computeDto.getPharmacie().getMotiRefuse()!= null ? computeDto.getPharmacie().setMotiRefuse("traitement en chevauchement non pris en charge "): "");
```

you can't do this in one statement. please split them into two :

```
computeDto.getPharmacie().setMotiRefuse("traitement en chevauchement non pris en charge ");
result.put("motifPharmacie",computeDto.getPharmacie().getMotiRefuse()!= null ? computeDto.getPharmacie().getMotiRefuse(): "");
```

The reason is: set method returns void
so the operand "?" sees that you returned void or string which are not compatible. so use get method in the ternary operator "?" instead of set.

Comment: Thanks it worked ! but why the value dosnt change in database ! when i refresh the page it disappear

Comment: Good. for database persistence, you should save the object using repository or Dao, or whatever the way used in the app.